# How do I link an internal JavaScript file to my HTML file in GitHub

Tags: javascript, html, file, canvas

Got to the link: https://github.com/FootballCoder/YearOfCode

As you can see, I have a folder called projects.

In that folder I have two subfolders, js and css.

I know how to link my CSS files, so don't worry about the css file.

The JavaScript is another story.

Go to the mousecoordinates.html file. In that file, I have linked the JavaScript and CSS files. But the Javascript file isn't being linked correctly.

Any suggestions on how to link it.

So far I have done:

```
<script src="./js/mousecoordinates.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding the script file type?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/mousecoordinates.js" ></script>
```

Comment: I have to wait 7 minutes until I can accept it as an answer